# USB devices (trackball and PS2-to-usb keyboard) stop responding in Ubuntu Mate 16.04.4

Tags: 16.04, drivers, usb, mouse, suspend

I am facing the problem described in the thread: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2342985

It affects the Logitech trackman wheel & the Keyboard.

And my problem is that I don't know how to do the : **quirk HID_QUIRK_ALWAYS_POLL (0x00000400)**, which is mentioned in the above link.

**where** should i look to find the proper file in order to change **something**? I am using Ubuntu Mate.

`lsusb` for the 2 devices gives:

```
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 046d:c404 Logitech, Inc. TrackMan Wheel
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 0a81:0205 Chesen Electronics Corp. PS/2 Keyboard+Mouse Adapter
```

`tlp-stat -u` for the 2 devices gives:

```
Bus 002 Device 009 ID 046d:c404 control = on,   autosuspend_delay_ms = -1000 -- Logitech, Inc. TrackMan Wheel (usbhid)
Bus 002 Device 010 ID 0a81:0205 control = on,   autosuspend_delay_ms = -1000 -- Chesen Electronics Corp. PS/2 Keyboard+Mouse Adapter (usbhid)
```

`uname -ra` gives

```
Linux dell 4.13.0-39-generic #44~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 5 16:43:10 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I think the problem is not related with autosuspend, but rather with buffer overflow for the specific devices due to that they are not supported in the kernel code.

### Update 1

This is unfortunately not an answer, but rather points to start looking to another direction, i.e. BIOS. Even though the USB trackball is detected within Ubuntu Mate when executing `lsusb` command, the trackball misbehaves probably due to an issue with BIOS. Check the output of the following command, especially the lines at the end.

```
$ dmesg | grep 2-1.2   
 [    1.900039] usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
 [    2.020547] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c404
 [    2.020554] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
 [    2.020559] usb 2-1.2: Product: Trackball
 [    2.020564] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Logitech
 [    2.033380] input: Logitech Trackball as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/0003:046D:C404.0001/input/input8
 [    3.488019] usb 2-1.2: reset low-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
 [    3.789745] usb 2-1.2: device firmware changed
 [    3.790112] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 4
 [    3.924089] usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
 [    4.040117] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c404
 [    4.040124] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
 [    4.040129] usb 2-1.2: Product: Trackball
 [    4.040133] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Logitech
 [    4.044948] input: Logitech Trackball as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/0003:046D:C404.0002/input/input10
 [    5.800078] usb 2-1.2: reset low-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
 [    7.844136] usb 2-1.2: reset low-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
 [    8.145979] usb 2-1.2: device firmware changed
 [    8.146222] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 6
 [    8.264032] usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
 [    8.381466] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c404
 [    8.381473] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
 [    8.381478] usb 2-1.2: Product: Trackball
 [    8.381483] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Logitech
 [    8.388461] usbhid 2-1.2:1.0: can't add hid device: -32
 [    8.388469] usbhid: probe of 2-1.2:1.0 failed with error -32
```

### Update 2

IMO this is important, so I am posting it

For some reason the Trackball is alive - **for at least 20' so far** - so I executed the command `dmesg | grep 2-1.2` again to check what it gives on the output when the trackball functions properly:

```
[    1.896048] usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[    2.010037] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c404
[    2.010039] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.010040] usb 2-1.2: Product: Trackball
[    2.010042] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Logitech
[    2.021341] input: Logitech Trackball as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/0003:046D:C404.0001/input/input8
```

### Update 3

Below is the output of the command `dmesg | grep 2-1.2` when the USB Trackball device does not respond at all:

```
[    1.851702] input: CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/0003:0A81:0205.0001/input/input8

[    1.908511] input: CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.1/0003:0A81:0205.0002/input/input9
[    1.912113] usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[    2.029673] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c404
[    2.029680] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.029685] usb 2-1.2: Product: Trackball
[    2.029689] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Logitech
[    2.034921] input: Logitech Trackball as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/0003:046D:C404.0003/input/input10
[ 1872.440676] usb 2-1.2: reset low-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 2458.374411] usb 2-1.2: reset low-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 2458.642416] usb 2-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 2472.750656] usb 2-1.2: reset low-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 2496.911127] usb 2-1.2: reset low-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 2706.502301] usb 2-1.2: reset low-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 2706.770215] usb 2-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
```

And below the output of the same command when the USB Trackball is back in life:

```
[    1.851702] input: CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/0003:0A81:0205.0001/input/input8
[    1.908511] input: CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.1/0003:0A81:0205.0002/input/input9
[    1.912113] usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[    2.029673] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c404
[    2.029680] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.029685] usb 2-1.2: Product: Trackball
[    2.029689] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Logitech
[    2.034921] input: Logitech Trackball as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/0003:046D:C404.0003/input/input10
[ 1872.440676] usb 2-1.2: reset low-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 2458.374411] usb 2-1.2: reset low-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 2458.642416] usb 2-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 2472.750656] usb 2-1.2: reset low-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 2496.911127] usb 2-1.2: reset low-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 2706.502301] usb 2-1.2: reset low-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 2706.770215] usb 2-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 2720.342390] usb 2-1.2: reset low-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 2744.194663] usb 2-1.2: reset low-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 4084.945618] usb 2-1.2: reset low-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 4174.840297] usb 2-1.2: reset low-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 4277.658573] input: CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/0003:0A81:0205.0004/input/input21
[ 4277.726031] input: CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.1/0003:0A81:0205.0005/input/input22
[ 4408.074526] usb 2-1.2: reset low-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 4533.168035] input: CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/0003:0A81:0205.0006/input/input23
[ 4533.243550] input: CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.1/0003:0A81:0205.0007/input/input24
[ 4597.074360] usb 2-1.2: reset low-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 4629.927191] usb 2-1.2: reset low-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 4728.505113] usb 2-1.2: reset low-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 4877.560053] input: CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/0003:0A81:0205.0008/input/input25
[ 4877.631227] input: CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.1/0003:0A81:0205.0009/input/input26
[ 4926.383190] usb 2-1.2: reset low-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 4928.815665] usb 2-1.2: reset low-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 2720.342390] usb 2-1.2: reset low-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 2744.194663] usb 2-1.2: reset low-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 4084.945618] usb 2-1.2: reset low-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 4174.840297] usb 2-1.2: reset low-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 4277.658573] input: CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/0003:0A81:0205.0004/input/input21
[ 4277.726031] input: CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.1/0003:0A81:0205.0005/input/input22
[ 4408.074526] usb 2-1.2: reset low-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 4533.168035] input: CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/0003:0A81:0205.0006/input/input23
[ 4533.243550] input: CHESEN PS2 to USB Converter as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.1/0003:0A81:0205.0007/input/input24
```

Comment: @dsstorefile  Yes, I did this prior to posting here. When I run the following command: `cat /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend` , the output is **-1**

Comment: "control = on" means in fact that autosuspend *is* disabled. TLP exempts input devices by default, no config needed.

Comment: I just added the following in /etc/default/grub :  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash usbcore.autosuspend=-1 usbhid.quirks=0x046d:0xc404:0x00000400"` . Let's see if this can fix the problem with the TrackMan Wheel.

Comment: ..then executed `sudo update-grub` & `reboot`..

Comment: Behavior is better, freezes seem to occur less frequently. However, I cannot consider this matter as solved.

Comment: unfortunately the problem is not solved. eventually it appears that both USB devices freeze very often, actually most of the time!

Comment: I tried the following, but didn't work: http://hamwaves.com/usb.autosuspend/en/index.html

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately not an answer, but rather points to start looking to another direction, i.e. BIOS. Even though the USB trackball is detected within Ubuntu Mate when executing `lsusb` command, the trackball misbehaves probably due to an issue with BIOS. Check the output of the following command, especially the lines at the end.

```
$ dmesg | grep 2-1.2  
[    1.900039] usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[    2.020547] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c404
[    2.020554] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.020559] usb 2-1.2: Product: Trackball
[    2.020564] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Logitech
[    2.033380] input: Logitech Trackball as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/0003:046D:C404.0001/input/input8
[    3.488019] usb 2-1.2: reset low-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[    3.789745] usb 2-1.2: device firmware changed
[    3.790112] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[    3.924089] usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[    4.040117] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c404
[    4.040124] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    4.040129] usb 2-1.2: Product: Trackball
[    4.040133] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Logitech
[    4.044948] input: Logitech Trackball as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/0003:046D:C404.0002/input/input10
[    5.800078] usb 2-1.2: reset low-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[    7.844136] usb 2-1.2: reset low-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[    8.145979] usb 2-1.2: device firmware changed
[    8.146222] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 6
[    8.264032] usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[    8.381466] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c404
[    8.381473] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    8.381478] usb 2-1.2: Product: Trackball
[    8.381483] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Logitech
[    8.388461] usbhid 2-1.2:1.0: can't add hid device: -32
[    8.388469] usbhid: probe of 2-1.2:1.0 failed with error -32
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO this is important, so I am posting it

For some reason the Trackball is alive - **for at least 20' so far** - so I executed the command `dmesg | grep 2-1.2` again to check what it gives on the output when the trackball functions properly:

```
[    1.896048] usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[    2.010037] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c404
[    2.010039] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.010040] usb 2-1.2: Product: Trackball
[    2.010042] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Logitech
[    2.021341] input: Logitech Trackball as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/0003:046D:C404.0001/input/input8
```